# Azure Service Fabric Actor Retry Logic on Exception

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm working on a Azure Service Fabric solution. 
I have implemented an Actor with some state, everything works fine.
Can anyone explain me , what happens if an user exception is thrown in my Actor implementation? What does the Service Fabric Environment do if a call to an actor throws an exception. Is there any default retry logic, that Forces the call again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Service Fabric Actors - unhandled exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191068/azure-service-fabric-actors-unhandled-exceptions)

Answer (score 2):

If an actor throws an exception, it gets handled inside [ActorRemotingExceptionHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt694591.aspx) or other default implementation of `IExceptionHandler`. Currently, if the exception is an ordinary exception which is not related to network issues or cluster or nodes availability, it will be rethrown on the client side where you will be able to handle it.

Comment: OK, in my situation I have hosted a WebApi Controller in the Cluster. The Controller calls an actor with some state. If an Excption is thrown in my actor implementation, the call to the actor never returns. Everything works fine in my LocalCluster but in the Azure Cluster the call never returns.

Comment: @M009 are you sure that you have the same type of exception in your local env and in Azure? And do you have the same versions of SDK installed? Are you using latest?

Comment: @M009 and what type of exception you are getting?

Comment: I found the Problem. The exception that was thrown in my actor implementation was a custom exception and was not marked as 'Serializable'. I got some communication exception from Service fabric internals. The Default retry logic did always execute the actor request again.